# MathJax escape sequences don't work

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview, google-chrome

The equation `$x = \{y\}$` is supposed to render like this `x = {y}` but instead in the preview pane it looks like this `x = y`. The escape sequences for curly braces, `\{` and `\}`, do not render correctly. This is a recent problem (I posted a question with curly braces a couple months ago and it rendered correctly)

This seems like a bug (unless there's been some undocumented recent change to MathJax?). FWIW, my browser is Chrome version 111.0.5563.65 (on Windows 10)

*Update:* I tried on the Edge browser and it works as expected. So this looks like a Chrome-specific bug

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, a similar problem was reported about 6 days ago on the Mathematics Meta site at [Why would escaped curly braces not be displayed by the mathjax plug-in?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35557/602049), although it's not clear from what's written there if it's an issue with just the preview, or also when the OP viewed the posted result.

Comment: I hope I posted this in the right place?  All the sub-sites (meta, vs math meta, etc.) is very confusing

Comment: Due to MathJax being used on multiple SE sites then, as far as I know (and also based on what I've seen in several other questions here), posting here should be fine.

Comment: Is it perhaps another one of [them MathJax/Markdown interactions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387100/620615)?

Comment: Does it work if you submit the post? If not, is there a certain number of backslashes that does work?

Comment: Didn’t try submitting the question (don’t want to submit a mangled question) There’s no end to hypothetical workarounds I could randomly try, but I think I’ll let Stackexchange’s engineering department take it from here.

Comment: Doubtful it’s a MathJax/Markdown interaction. Problem occurs even with *just* the simple equation mentioned in my post.

Comment: If you do want to try in a real post, you can use the [Math Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370).

Comment: These posts seem related: [Escaped braces do not render in post preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31124) on [math.meta.se], 
[Braces are not rendered in MathJax in the preview of a question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5163) on MathOverflow Meta.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that preview has problems with backslash in several instances.

For example, if I try this text:

```
$\{x\}=\{y\}$

$r(ξ, \bar{ξ}) = \frac{1}{\#} \sum_{g ∈ } r_0 (g(ξ), g(\bar{ξ}))$

$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_3 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 
\end{pmatrix}$
```

It either renders incorrectly or not at all in the preview after entering the question:

[image: screenshot]

However, after the question is posted, everything looks fine - the screenshot is below and people with 10k+ reputation points on Mathematics can [see the question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4863510):

[image: screenshot]

Once the question was posted, after clicking on edit, the preview behaves correctly:

[image: screenshot]

The examples used above are based on various bug reports, such as:
[Missing brackets in ${x}$ in drafts, not missing in the final question/product](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5875) and
[Including a hash character (#) in a math equation causes it to not render (in new-question page)](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5871). Problem with `\\` - which is used as a newline in various matrix-like environments - was mentioned here: [MathJax preview renders slowly and improperly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388810). At some point in the distant past it was recommended to use `\\\\` instead - but as you can see, `\\` clearly works now *in the final post*; the problem is only in the preview before posting. See here: [Using the align environment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3514#3526)