# MathJax preview renders slowly and improperly

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown-preview, math-se

When writing expressions in the body with [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) on the *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, the preview is sometimes immediate, but oftentimes it takes maybe a good five seconds to render. In the latter case, it also doesn't format everything properly. For example, when writing code like below, the "`\\`" expression doesn't get recognized as new line. I have been experiencing this problem for maybe over a year on the website. Sometimes I can fix the problem by refreshing the page, but most of the time it doesn't work.

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a *hard* refresh?

This clears the cache for a specific page.

If you're using Google Chrome ...

- on a Windows computer, it's:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- on a Mac, it's:
  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>